# Filament translation stoped working after Laravel translations was implemented

Tags: laravel, translation, laravel-10, lang, laravel-filament

I am building a laravel project with filament.
Everything worked normally, but after working on translations in Laravel, the Fillament translations stopped working.

Has anyone ever experienced this?
I published fillament and laravel translation files already. Also published fillament views but could not find/replace the labels to test.

Maybe I need to override Laravel translations to Filament translations? Is that even possible to do and not break the project?

I will insert the before and after images.

[image: This is how it was]

[image: This is how it is after laravel translations]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the locale and the fallback_locale that were both assigned to pt. I change the locale to en and the fallback to pt_PT. This solved the issue.